# How do I get an IP address from an EditText box?

Tags: java, android

Hi I am quite new to android and i'm sorry if its a silly question.

How do I use an EditText box instead of having the IP address hard coded. 
As you can see from the code below I have to put the computers ip address that im connecting to in, what I want to do is make it so I use an EditText box instead such as:

```
String input= edittextIP.getText().toString();
```

But i could not get this to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
public class Client {


private String serverMessage;
public final String SERVERIP = "100.100.100.61"; //computer IP address
public final int SERVERPORT = 4444;
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
private boolean mRun = false;



PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;


/**
 *  Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
 */
public Client(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Sends the message entered by client to the server
 * @param message text entered by client
 */
public void sendMessage(String message){
    if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        out.println(message);
        out.flush();
    }
}

public void stopClient(){
    mRun = false;
}

public void run() {

    mRun = true;

    try {

        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        try {

            //send the message to the server
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

            //receive the message which the server sends back
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
            while (mRun) {
                serverMessage = in.readLine();

                if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                }
                serverMessage = null;

            }


            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");


        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

        } finally {
            //the socket must be closed. I can't reconnect to this socket
            // after it is closed, which means a new socket has to be created.
            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

    }

}


/// public EditText findViewByid(int edittextIP) {   <--- this was previous try please 
///                                                          disregard this
///     
///     return null;
/// }


public interface OnMessageReceived {
    public void messageReceived(String message);
}
}
```

This is my activity below:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
private ListView mList;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
private Adapter mAdapter;
private Client mTcpClient;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send_button);



    mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    mAdapter = new Adapter(this, arrayList);
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // connect to the server
    new connectTask().execute("");


    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String message = editText.getText().toString();


            arrayList.add("c: " + message);

            //sends the message to the server
            if (mTcpClient != null) {
                mTcpClient.sendMessage(message);
            }

            //refresh the list
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            editText.setText("");
        }
    });

}

public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,Client> {

    @Override
    protected Client doInBackground(String... message) {

        //create a TCPClient object and
        mTcpClient = new Client(new Client.OnMessageReceived() {

            //here the messageReceived is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {

                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        arrayList.add(values[0]);

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why or better what does that not work for you?

Comment: "But i could not get this to work." what aspect of it can you not get to work? If you can be more specific about what problems you are having it will be easier for us to help you resolve them

Comment: where is the activity?

Comment: I have added my activity as requested. I could not get this line: InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);    to listen to an EditText.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to cast the value and generated an wrong stub. You need to delete your findViewByid function. Try this code:

```
TextEdit input = (TextEdit)findViewByid(...);
```

Note that you should pass directly the IP to your class from your activity for example thrue the constructor:

```
public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,Client> {
    private string ip;
    public ConnectTask(String ip) {
        this.ip=ip;
    }
 // ...
```

There you have the IP in the member variable ip. You can set it like this:

```
ConnectTask task = new ConnectTask(input.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, where do you want me to put that. Sorry I have tried that code it in multiple places before hand but could not get it to work.

Comment: You can do this thrue the constructor... I'll add an example by the way you should besser use a seperat thread. (`new Thread(new Runnable() {void run() {/*your code*/}).start();*`).

Answer (score 0):

You should get the EditText instance from your Activity (the class that extends from Activity), your "findViewById" function has no sense there. "findViewById" is a method inherited from Activity. Then, you could pass the text typed in that EditText from your Activity to your Client instance, for example.

Comment: Sorry that findviewbyid was from me getting desperate earlier ha